# Initiate a selection via Button

Tags: android, material-design

In the Material design guidelines for [selecting multiple items](https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/selection.html#selection-item-selection), it is stated that a selection is initiated by a gesture

> When initiating selection, both long-press and two-finger touch may be extended using a drag gesture to select multiple items. Items between the beginning and end points of the drag will be included in the selection.

But doesn't the user need a way to initiate a selection without knowing the gesture, i.e. by pressing a button?

Is there any best practice or other section in the design guide?

On iOS there is always this "Edit" button to start a selection ([see this screenshot](http://simplicitybliss.com/post/124943235147/quick-ios-mailbox-access)).

Comment: For me a long-press is the trigger to select an item in a list. I think its a common pattern in combination with actionbar / toolbar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an answer in the very [same section in the design guide](https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/selection.html), just a little further up:

> The global gesture to select data is a long-press, a touch or mousedown that’s held in the same position for a moment. A two-finger touch may also trigger selection on touch devices.

So no, there is no expectation for there to be an "edit" button to enable selection like in iOS. The long-press-to-select gesture is the canonical way to start selecting items on Android.